# How to get the Google ad manager impression of a placement using api (PHP)?

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I am able to connect with my ad manager account using Google Ad Manager API (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/tree/master/examples/AdManager). I am getting data i.e all companies, all placement on my command line. But confused on getting impressions.

> How to get an impression of a placement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need a query. Using the UI is the easiest way to build a query, and see the results. Here's the [guide](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/2643320?hl=en&ref_topic=7492017#) from Google to create a query on the UI.

Then, you will save the query and follow the `ReportService/RunSavedQuery.php` [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdManager/v201811/ReportService/RunSavedQuery.php) to download the impression report in your program.

Please note that the examples are removed every 4 quarters and replaced by newer examples. So, if the example link above doesn't work, the example might have been replaced with a newer one.

This question is not a PHP specific question. Indeed, it is a "how to use the product" question, and is best suitable to be answered on the Google Ad Manager [product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/dfp). If you raise a question on the forum, the support staff may get back to you on a secured channel to help you build the query.